# Is there any way to see who deleted a view?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL 2008, is there any way to see details about a deleted view.  In particular who might have done it or at least when?

Comment: That's not me, I swear.

Comment: Although I was initially accused.  The problem with that was that I wasn't even here. ;)

Comment: What do your logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two things:

1. If you are on SQL Server 2005 and above you can interrogate the [default trace](http://www.eraofdata.com/blog/2009/09/the-sql-server-default-trace/) to see what happened.
2. You can try querying the cache and see the queries issued(If the query is still in the cache and not flushed out)

Comment: I looked at the tracing information.  There wasn't anything in there for the time period.  So I widened my search, and the only thing that seems to show up are some backup events

Comment: For the future you can set up auditing...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015(SQL.100).aspx

Comment: +1 for how to figure this out in the future

Answer (score 0):

Not certain, but this might help:

DBCC Log (your_data_basename, parameter)  where parameter is 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

0 is basic info, 4 is full info.

Comment: I don't think I'm smart enough to read that. ;)

Comment: The closest you might be able to get to answer is a list of those who would have sufficient permission to do so. This might be the beginning of a case to limit who is db_owner or in the sysadmin server role, especially if you are the first stop in the hunt.   This is also the kind of circumstance where the thinking of those who like to jump to the favorite conclusion is displayed.